# How can I copy a local image file from my computer to a remote server using Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, scp, nano

I completely new to using Terminal on Mac. My teacher has a server set up for my php course and is asking that we upload our website files to his server. I’ve figured out how to create files using nano and add those to the server, but I need to get an image for my site into the folder I’ve created. How do I transfer the image files I need so that my site displays them from his server?

Answer (score 2):

If you end up with : it will place copy of file inside home directory of the user

```
scp /path-to-file user@host:/path
```